# Make a window dockable to the Windows desktop

Tags: desktop, dockable, dockable-windows

The latest (and unfortunately the last) version of WinAMP provides a feature named 'Docked toolbar'.

I've found a screenshot on the Web, showing what it looks like. If you docks the WinAMP window to the bottom, for instance, another window doesn't overlap it, even maximized:

[image: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v514/Matheusoc/netscape.jpg]

The question is what programming technique provides this docking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what should be used — ADT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx